# Bayesian predictions from posterior parameter distributions

Tags: bayesian, posterior

I have two physical models $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ (not probability distributions) parameterized on the same set of parameters $\theta$. I also have data $y$ with measurement noise $\epsilon$ which can be used to obtain posterior estimates $p(\theta | y)$ through one of the models:
\begin{align}
  y &= f(\theta) + \epsilon \\
  \text{where}\ \epsilon &\sim \text{Normal}(0, \sigma)
\end{align}
so a Gaussian likelihood function can be defined:
\begin{equation}
p(y | \theta) \sim \exp\left(\frac{-(y - f(\theta))^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
\end{equation}

Questions:

1. Most of what I've read seems to be concerned with constructing posterior
   predictive distributions for new $y$ (denoting as $y_{\text{new}}$),
   as in $p(y_{\text{new}}|y) = \int p(y_{\text{new}}|\theta)
   p(\theta|y)d\theta$. But don't I just want the parameter-weighted distribution $f(\theta)p(\theta|y)$
   without the measurement noise $\epsilon$ for the best estimate of $f(\theta)$?
2. Letting $z=g(\theta)$, is it necessary to specify a probability density function $p(z|\theta)$ so that new predictions of $z$ are defined as the marginal distribution $p(z|y) = \int p(z|\theta)
   p(\theta|y)d\theta$ (e.g., Robert, *The Bayesian Choice*, 2007)? Can I not just construct a probability distribution for the second
   physical model from $g(\theta)p(\theta|y)$? For instance using MCMC I could construct the probability distribution from the sequence $\{g(\theta_1), g(\theta_2), \ldots, g(\theta_t)\}$.

Comment: When I started reading the question, I had the impression that $\theta$ was a fixed (but unknown) parameter, but at the end of the question $\theta$ is given an index that makes it seem more like a stochastic process. Did you really mean something like $y_t = f(x_t,\theta) + \varepsilon_t$ and $z_t = g(w_t,\theta) + e_t$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the indices are meant to signify realizations generated by MCMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Most of what I've read seems to be concerned with constructing posterior
>      predictive distributions for new $y$ (denoting as $y_{\text{new}}$),
>      as in $p(y_{\text{new}}|y) = \int p(y_{\text{new}}|\theta)
>         p(\theta|y)d\theta$. But don't I just want the parameter-weighted distribution $f(\theta)p(\theta|y)$
>      without the measurement noise $\epsilon$ for the best estimate of $f(\theta)$?

Expected value from the posterior distribution is "best" only in terms of minimizing squared error (for details, check *The Bayesian Choice*, already mentioned by you), but you could want instead look at other statistics, for example median of the posterior distribution (minimize absolute loss), or mode (*maximum a posteriori* estimate), etc. If you have estimate of the posterior distribution, you can easily estimate *any* of those quantities.

> 2. Letting $z=g(\theta)$, is it necessary to specify a probability density function $p(z|\theta)$ so that new predictions of $z$ are
>      defined as the marginal distribution $p(z|y) = \int p(z|\theta)
>         p(\theta|y)d\theta$ (e.g., Robert, *The Bayesian Choice*, 2007)? Can I not just construct a probability distribution for the second
>      physical model from $g(\theta)p(\theta|y)$? For instance using MCMC I could construct the probability distribution from the sequence
>      $\{g(\theta_1), g(\theta_2), \ldots, g(\theta_t)\}$.

By the [law of unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

$$
E[g(x)] = \int g(x)\,p(x)\, dx
$$

If you have samples from the posterior distribution of $\tilde\theta_1,\tilde\theta_2,\dots,\tilde\theta_n \sim p(\theta|y)$, then to obtain the samples of their transformations, you just need to transform the samples; to get estimate of the expected value of the transformation of $\theta$, just calculate the empirical mean of the transformed MCMC samples.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the "mean" was best - only that the posterior mode, mean, median etc. for $f$ could be calculated from the distribution $f(\theta)p(\theta|y)$ instead of invoking the likelihood function $p(y|\theta)$. But great to have confirmation on LOTUS.

Comment: @hatmatrix *if* you have way of estimating $p(\theta|y)$ without using Bayes theorem, then yes, you don't need likelihood, but usually don't have other way.

Comment: For prediction, to reproduce $y$-like data I need the likelihood, but if I'm actually interested in $f$ or $g$ I don't need to use the likelihood again after using it for estimation of $p(\theta|y)$.

Comment: @hatmatrix yes, if you already know the posterior, you don't need the likelihood, since you needed the likelihood only to estimate the posterior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I think most textbooks seem focused on reproducing $y$ so they show the posterior distribution for prediction shown in the form above, but I just wanted a sanity check that the posterior parameter distribution can be used to derive distributions for other models (using for instance theorem of the unconscious statistician).